# Compilation of vhdl code

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

I am constantly getting this message- "# Compile of 1stfile.vhd failed with 0 errors." whenever I am trying to compile my file "1stfile.vhd", what should I do ?

Comment: Your question does not have nearly enough information. What are the contents of 1stfile.vhd? What is the full compile report/transcript? Using what version (of ModelSim, I assume)?

Answer (score 2):

Try using a name that doesn't start with a number.  Identifiers in VHDL cannot start with numbers.  That shouldn't affect what you can name a file, but it might depending on the tool-chain you're using and it's an easy theory to test.